# ms-xhelp not recognised

Tags: chm

I'm trying to get to grips with the relatively new help system fronted by Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0.

I've found the SDK (at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14923) and have started working through it. I've used Help Library Manager to add the modified help file in step 9 of the "Walkthrough: Branding Package and Content" tutorial, but step 10 tells me to view help by typing a command into a command prompt that starts "ms-xhelp:///". The command prompt responds with a generic unrecognised command response. Pasting the whole thing into Chrome just does a Google search, so obviously that's not recognising it, and pasting it into Internet Explorer attempts to start doing something but then pops a message up "There was a problem sending the command to the program".

Remarkably, this appears to be the first post on here containing "ms-xhelp", and no tags seem directly relevant.

I do have VS2010 installed and it runs help correctly. If I modify the tail end of the URL the web browser opens in, I can get at the newly installed help file, but piggybacking on something that knows what it's doing is unsatisfactory and doesn't show me where things are going wrong. Does anyone know why the "ms-xhelp" approach isn't working?